# Как перевести массив рун в строку

Tags: строки, golang

Срез рун перевести в строку не составляет труда.

А как перевести массив рун в строку?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := [2]rune{'a', 'b'}
    b := []rune{'a', 'b'}
    fmt.Println(string(a)) // Так сделать нельзя
    fmt.Println(string(b))  // А так можно
}
```

Понятно, что можно написать свою функцию:

```
func ToString(arr *[2]rune) string {
    runeArr := make([]rune, 0, 2)
    for i := range *arr {
        runeArr = append(runeArr, (*arr)[i])
    }
    return string(runeArr)
}
```

но хотелось бы обойтись встроенными методами.

Comment: `fmt.Println(string(a[:]))`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать

```
fmt.Println(string(a[:]))
```

Здесь в `string` кастуется срез (слайс), созданный из массива `a`. То есть фактически даже новая память не выделяется, в то время как в функции `ToString` память выделяется под новый срез (слайс), который по сути, того же размера что и исходный массив.